# How to add filters to Grizzly server?

Tags: java, authentication, redirect, grizzly, whitelist

I've created a Grizzly server that returns JSON. It works nicely:

```
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.mypackage");
    resourceConfig.setApplicationName("My-Service");
    resourceConfig.register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
    server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, resourceConfig);
```

I need **filters** that

- Check if the Authorization header contains a valid key
- Responds with 302/redirect if `x-forwarded-proto` is `http` (with location set to the `https` equivalent)
- Responds with 403/forbidden if `x-forwarded-for` is not on a white list

Right now I do these checks like this:

```
@Path("v1")
public class Facade {

    @GET
    @Path("/getinfo/{infotype}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getNextPwc(@HeaderParam("authorization") String authorizationKey,
            @Context Request request, 
            @HeaderParam("x-forwarded-proto") String xForwardedProto, 
            @HeaderParam("x-forwarded-for") String xForwardedFor,
            @PathParam("infotype") String infoType) {
        Response errorResponse = getErrorResponse(authorizationKey, request, xForwardedFor, xForwardedProto);
        if (errorResponse != null) {
            return errorResponse;
        }
        ... start work with infoType here ...
```

It works - the server behaves correctly - but the code is in the **wrong place** (and I have to remember to add it to all new methods) so I would like to move it to a filter mechanism instead.

Any help is very appreciated.

(I know the `x-forwarded-proto` and `x-forwarded-for` checks are not bullet proof, but it is better than nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

updated:
this works, although it's probably not how it was supposed to be set up:

```
final HttpServer server = new HttpServer();

final NetworkListener networkListener = new NetworkListener(
    "secured-listener",
    "0.0.0.0",
    9191
);
server.addListener(networkListener);
server.start();

networkListener.getFilterChain().add(5, new BaseFilter(){
    @Override
    public NextAction handleRead(FilterChainContext ctx) throws IOException {
        return super.handleRead(ctx);
    }
});
System.in.read();
```

Notice index in getFilterChain().add( - the filter should be before HttpServerFilter cause it returns STOP action.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give this a try! But how are "your" `transport` and "my" `server` connected?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Now I'm starting to understand.